# Home Work Question C# function returns "System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[Exercise6.Exercise6+Student,System.String]"

Tags: c#

On **Question 6.4** --> last function **"PrintTopStudents()"**

**You can ignore 1 and 2- code not related.
only 3-4 is about the issue.**

return this:
**"System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[Exercise6.Exercise6+Student,System.String]"**

the function purpose is to get top above 80 grades of students from a collection list

I tried to debug but cant find the issue.
I think the lists stays empty

**Why is that?**

thanks.

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    
    namespace Exercise6
    {
        class Exercise6
        {
            //1. Create a function that receives a List of numbers and returns the sum of them.
            static int GetSum(List<int> lst)
            {
                var sum = lst.Sum();
    
                return sum;
            }
    
            //2.Create a function that receives a List of booleans
            //and returns then number of “true” occurrences
            static int CountTrue(List<bool> lst)
            {
                return lst.Where(x => x == true).Count();
            }
    
    
            //3. Crate a Class called Student with :
            //Data Members:
            //-Name
            //-Grades(a private List of numbers)
            //Functions:
            //-AddGrade – receive a grade and add it to the list
            //-GetAvg – returns the grades average
            class Student
            {
                public string name;
                private List<int> grades = new List<int>();
    
                public void AddGrade(int grade)
                {
                    grades.Add(grade);
                }
    
                public double GetAvg()
                {
                    return grades.Average();
                }
            }
    
            //4.Crate a Class called School with :
            //Data Members:
            //-Students(a private List of Student objects)
            //Functions:
            //-AddStudent – receive a student object and add it to the list
            //-PrintAvgs– Print all students averages
            class School
            {
                private List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
                public void AddStudent(Student s)
                {
                    students.Add(s);
                }
    
                public void PrintAvgs()
                {
                    foreach (var stud in students)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(stud.GetAvg());
                    }
                }
    
                public void PrintTopStudents()
                {
                    
                    //Get the names of top avg students
                    //Where-Like "Filter" in JS
                    //Select-Like "Map" in JS
                    var names = students.Where(x => x.GetAvg() > 80).Select(x => x.name);
                    Console.WriteLine(names);
                }
    
            }
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                //1.
                Console.WriteLine("Exercise 1");
                var nums = new List<int>();
                nums.Add(7);
                nums.Add(2);
                nums.Add(18);
                nums.Add(32);
    
                var result = GetSum(nums);
    
                Console.WriteLine(result);
                Console.WriteLine("");
    
                //2.
                Console.WriteLine("Exercise 2");
                List<bool> arr = new List<bool>();
                arr.Add(true);
                arr.Add(false);
                arr.Add(true);
                arr.Add(false);
                arr.Add(false);
                arr.Add(true);
    
                var result2 = CountTrue(arr);
                Console.WriteLine(result2);
                Console.WriteLine("");
    
    
                //3.
                Console.WriteLine("Exercise 3");
                Student s1 = new Student();
                s1.name = "Boaz";
                s1.AddGrade(78);
                s1.AddGrade(56);
                s1.AddGrade(98);
                s1.AddGrade(87);
    
                var avg = s1.GetAvg();
                Console.WriteLine(avg);
                Console.WriteLine("");
    
                //4.
                Console.WriteLine("Exercise 4");
                Student s2 = new Student();
                s2.name = "Ron";
                s2.AddGrade(77);
                s2.AddGrade(79);
                s2.AddGrade(86);
                s2.AddGrade(89);
    
                Student s3 = new Student();
                s3.name = "Yaron";
                s3.AddGrade(56);
                s3.AddGrade(87);
                s3.AddGrade(98);
                s3.AddGrade(100);
    
                Student s4 = new Student();
                s4.name = "Valery";
                s4.AddGrade(56);
                s4.AddGrade(64);
                s4.AddGrade(78);
                s4.AddGrade(91);
    
                Student s5 = new Student();
                s5.name = "Daniel";
                s5.AddGrade(49);
                s5.AddGrade(60);
                s5.AddGrade(66);
                s5.AddGrade(80);
    
                School school = new School();
                school.AddStudent(s1);
                school.AddStudent(s2);
                school.AddStudent(s3);
                school.AddStudent(s4);
                school.AddStudent(s5);
    
    
                Console.WriteLine("All students avgs");
                school.PrintAvgs();
    
                Console.WriteLine("");
    
                Console.WriteLine("Top students avgs");
                school.PrintTopStudents();
    
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: var names = students.Where(x => x.GetAvg() > 80).Select(x => x.name);
                    Console.WriteLine(names);

Comment: Read up on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-5.0#System_String_Join_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__

Comment: Hi,
Can i get a shortcut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code

```
var names = students.Where(x => x.GetAvg() > 80).Select(x => x.name);
Console.WriteLine(names);
```

`names` is a collection of names. I.e. there are/can be multiple names. When you write that to the console, C# doesn't know how to do it. So it prints the type of the variable.

To print out the names of the students, you can iterate over the collection like this

```
var names = students.Where(x => x.GetAvg() > 80).Select(x => x.name);
foreach (var name in names) {
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

To also print the average grade, you can change it so your Where returns the student instances rather than just the name. Like this

```
var topStudents = students.Where(x => x.GetAvg() > 80);
foreach (var topStudent in topStudents) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{topStudent.name} - {topStudent.GetAvg()}");
}
```

Comment: :*
Its OK now!
Thanks!!!!!!!!
Now if i want to show also the avg grade near their names in console?

Comment: @BenoMosko I've added code to print the average grade for each top student

Comment: Amazing,
I'll try to follow and understand whats going on there

Comment: @BenoMosko If you could give my answer a vote and mark it as accepted, that would be nice. I *need* my internet points :D

Comment: Sure,
i accepted it as answer,
but i need at least 15 point to vote it.

Comment: That's fine. Thanks!